# Get the word before exclamation mark in R tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I´m wondering how to get the words that occur before an exclamation mark! I have a dataframe with different strings on each row. I have tried following:

```
text %>%
    str_match("!",lines)
```

I don´t really get what I want and I´m a bit lost. Anyone has advice?

Comment: Hi - could you provide a bit more example data and expected output here please

Comment: It will be easier to help if you can post a sample of your data frame with ```dput()``` and the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You can `str_extract_all` the words before the `!` using lookahead:

Data:

```
text <- c("Hello!", "This a test sentence", "That's another test sentence, yes! It is!", "And that's one more")
```

Solution:

```
library(stringr)   
unlist(str_extract_all(text, "\\b\\w+\\b(?=!)"))
[1] "Hello" "yes"   "is"
```

If you seek a `dplyr` solution:

```
data.frame(text) %>%
  mutate(Word_before_excl = str_extract_all(text, "\\b\\w+\\b(?=!)"))
                                       text Word_before_excl
1                                    Hello!            Hello
2                      This a test sentence                 
3 That's another test sentence, yes! It is!          yes, is
4                       And that's one more
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we can use `regmatches`

```
> sapply(regmatches(text, gregexpr("\\b\\w+\\b(?=!)", text, perl = TRUE)), toString)
[1] "Hello"   ""        "yes, is" ""
```

Comment: OP is asking for a R tidyverse solution

Answer (score -1):

You could also use :

```
> unlist(strsplit("Dog!Cat!", "!"))
[1] "Dog" "Cat"
```

Comment: And what if the string is something like `That's a dog! Not a cat!`?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Good point.